# redux form custom value in input field

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I try to pass a custom input value into a field, i already use initialValue or dispatch change but i want to keep my object entirely but display only one value.

For example:

```
const value = { name:'bob', firstname:'lanvin', age:28 }

    <Field component={MyCustomInput} val="value.name"/>

    const MyCustomInput = (props, value) => {
      return (
        <div class="input-row">
          <input type="text" {...props} defaultValue="val"/>
          {props.touched && props.error && <span className="error">{props.error}</span>}
        </div>
      )
    }/>
```

I repeat this Field in some page so i want to display one time name and after age,... Which is the best way to do ?

Answer (score 0):

The value will be available as a prop to the component. You can handle it like

```
const value = { name:'bob', firstname:'lanvin', age:28 }

<Field component={MyCustomInput} val={value.name}/>

const MyCustomInput = (props) => {
  return (
    <div class="input-row">
      <input type="text" {...props} defaultValue={props.val}/>
      {props.touched && props.error && <span className="error">{props.error}</span>}
    </div>
  )
}/>
```

Comment: can you check what you get ain the MyCustomInput as a prop by console.log(), also I updated the answer to `val={value.name}`. Kindly check and let me know

Comment: When the component load, first it's undefined and after the value populate

Comment: With Redux form you need to explicitly set intialValue

Comment: I already set it in initialValues with the entire object after that i need in my component to get only two elements of this object like this :                       `<Field link component={RenderField} label="Interlocuteur" val={this.props.parametrage.entreprise.commercial.firstname+ ' ' + this.props.parametrage.entreprise.commercial.name} />`

Comment: In that case the props may not be available initially